# Jolt Transformation - pull up and rename field

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to write a jolt transformation with the below input:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "positions": {
      "positionEdge": [
        {
          "position": {
            "ref": "B125AE024:1:BASE",
            "catalogue": {
              "ref": "BASE:1"
            }
          },
          "cursor": "Y3Vyc29yOi0tLWMxMWYxYWQwLTE2MWEtNDNmNS05ZDM5LWMwODRiZTdiN2Q3OV9fMTY1NzQ5NTU5MTQ4Ng=="
        },
        {
          "position": {
            "ref": "B125AE024:2:AGGREGATE",
            "catalogue": {
              "ref": "ATS:1"
            }
          },
          "cursor": "Y3Vyc29yOi0tLWVmZDgwNTljLWYyNTctNDhhYy1hYzVlLWI3NzlhMjMyMTVmYl9fMTY1NzQ5NTU5MTI3MQ=="
        }
      ],
      "pageInfo": {
        "hasNextPage": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The expected output is:

```json
[
  {
    "ref": "B125AE024:1:BASE",
    "catalogueRef": "BASE:1"
  },
  {
    "ref": "B125AE024:2:AGGREGATE",
    "catalogueRef": "ATS:1"
  }
]
```

My current spec is:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "positions": {
          "positionEdge": {
            "*": {
              "position": {
                "@": ".",
                "catalogue": {
                  "ref": "catalogueRef"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "catalogue": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

which does not give me the desired result and is missing the catalogueRef of the 2nd record..

Can the result be achieved in a single transformation, i.e. rename the `catalogue.ref` field up and rename it to `catalogueRef`? I basically want to flatten the position records.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a single **shift** transformation spec, by walking through the **`"positionEdge"`** array, in a symbolical manner such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // stands for the level of the object "data"
        "*": { // the level of the object "positions"
          "*": { // the level of the array "positionEdge"
            "*": { //the indexes of the array "positionEdge"
              "position": { // the level of the object "position" 
                "*": "[#3].&", // going three levels up the tree to reach the level of "positionEdge" by three times traversing the "{" sign, and replicate "ref" attribute 
                "c*": { //the level of object "catalogue" -- else case
                  "*": "[#4].&1&" // going four levels up the tree to reach the level of "positionEdge", &1 brings the literal "catalogue", and & already replicates the level from the current level, eg. "ref"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo screenshot*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ (*the famous sandbox of the jolt*) is :

[image]

If the capital letter **R** is really needed, then you can convert the leaf node from

```json
"*": "[#4].&1&"
```

to

```json
"r*": "[#4].&1R&(0,1)" // where, in &(0,1); zero represents the current level, one represents the 1st occurence for the asterisk, which might be more than one, in order to generate the literal "ef"
```

Comment: nice solution. I have a doubt, could you pls tell me when to use [#] in brackets and when to use [&] in brackets. I am a bit confused regd. the usage of these wildcards. It seems like both solutions will work, but I want to understand which wildcard to use in which scenario. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @ayan_2587 . There's only one difference for the current case that `[#3]` is identical to `[&2]`, and `[#4]` is identical to `[&3]` as `#` wildcard counts the current level as well, and both will generate the same result; but `[&]` treats index dependent, and should start by the 0th index, otherwise yields `null`s and tends to produce array of obejcts, while `[#]` produces straight arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the spec to get the desired output

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "positions": {
          "positionEdge": {
            "*": {
              "position": {
                "ref": "[&2].ref",
                "catalogue": {
                  "ref": "[&3].catalogueRef"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! much appreciated @ayan_2587. Barbaros' answer is a bit more generic